# Determine whether a file was deleted or overwritten - Firebase Storage OnDelete()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is there a way to determine whether a file was truly deleted, or whether it was updated (overwritten) when `OnDelete()` is triggered, other than calling `file.exists()`?

`OnDelete()` is known to be triggered when a file was deleted or overwritten - this is an expected behavior, mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#trigger_a_function_on_changes).

I use it in my app when a user deletes his profile picture. So when triggered, I can't tell whether the picture was deleted or updated, because it'd be triggered in both cases. So I have to manually check what happened, and this is exactly my problem.

I can obviously use `file.exists()` for the job, but I consider it an expensive call (or am I wrong?) because this is accessing the storage again, and it seems like there must be a way to avoid it, but I'm not sure.

If there is no way, can I safely assume that `exists()` will never precede the overwrite event, causing a false negative? (I'm worried it would operate prior the overwrite completion, find no existing file, and return false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), if you use a versioning bucket, `OnDelete()` is only triggered "when a version is permanently deleted (**but not when an object is archived**)".

In order to transform your bucket to a versioning one, follow this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#enable

Comment: Thanks Renaud. it would surely help, however object versioning strategy has its own disadvantages which i'd like to avoid: more charge for data usage, and a new headache of handling archived files life-cycle. I'll accept your answer in a few days if no other one would pop up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My solution (written in Go, but the principle behind it remains the same) for when not using versioning:

```
func main(ctx context.Context, event GCSEvent) error {
    obj := bucket.Object(event.Name)
    _, err = obj.Attrs(ctx) // _ => objAttrs
    if err != nil {
        if err.Error() == "storage: object doesn't exist" {
            // This file is deleted, so execute a function
            onFileDeleted()
            return nil
        } else {
            // Something else went wrong, identify it
            log.Fatalf("Getting attributes error: %v", err, e.Name[7:27])
        }
    }
    // This means file was merely updated
    return nil
}

func onFileDeleted() {
  log.Println("File deleted")
}
```

And a short explanation:

1. Based on the filename, first get the reference to the object.
2. From the reference of the object, try reading the attributes.
3. If you encounter the error, check if that error is because the file doesn't exist.
4. If the error is correct, do what you want when the file **is deleted**.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but it seems to me not robust. This line: err.Error() == "storage: object doesn't exist" pretty hacky!

Comment: Perhaps, but there might be another way to use a template for the error which might be in the library somewhere for comparison instead, or there might be an error code hidden somewhere inside. Haven't delved too deeply into it back then. And things might have changed since as well, it's been a while... Keep me posted if you find a better alternative?

Comment: I did not find an easy solution so I decided to change my logic instead! I like FB but sometimes to overcome these lack of features are very time consuming.